# 10インチ以上のAndroidのタブレットのみ除外する方法

Tags: android

先日アプリをリリースしたところ、7インチ以上10インチ未満のタブレットの場合は正常に動作するのに、10インチ以上のタブレットの場合は不具合が発生してしまうことが発覚しました。
10インチ以上のタブレットは除外して、7インチ以上10インチ未満のタブレットのみインストールできるようにするにはAndroidManifest.xmlに何と記述したらいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

マニフェストへの記述だと、dp指定でしか除外できなかったと思います。この方法では近年の高解像度デバイスまで除外されてしまいますので、デヴェロッパーコンソールで問題が発生している端末を除外設定するのが良いでしょう。
ただ、端末依存のバグでないならばそれなりの数となって除外設定がややこしいことと、そもそもなんで10インチ以上のみで不具合が出るのかという根本的な問題がありますから、一番良いのはやはり動的な画面リサイズ関数かなにかで発生しているバグの原因究明ですね。